# How to find out which php files where used to render a page in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I tried using the devel query log which didn't help. Could I do this with a module?

I want to find out which file is used to generate the page to look at the code to possibly modify it / write a module for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `template.php` you can do this :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  if(isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] == 1) {
     dsm(menu_get_item(), 'Menu information'); // show all menu routing information
     dsm(debug_backtrace(), 'Backtrace'); // show coding tree execution in order
     dsm($vars, 'data'); // optionnally display datas available 
  }
}
```

use it like : http://www.mytestdomain.com/my-page-to-test.html?debug=1

NB : Clear cache before to use the first time

doc : 
[template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x)

[menu_get_item](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7.x)

[debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Answer (score 1):

Using debug_backtrace() may help you.
So if you want check "generate the page" process, you can put it in the specific page.tpl.php

```
var_dump(debug_backtrace());
```

Also this module can help check the page tpl using.
https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer